# angular ui-router goes to wrong state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a main index.html file which contains **ui-view**

which gets populated by (partial html templates) according to state in ui-router.

In one of those template I have defined two buttons both leads to diffrent routes (or states). Fist takes to the edit movie list and second takes you to create new movie.

But whenever second button is clicked, I don't know why second state's view never shows. First states shows instead of it.

I have checked with both controllers and templates I see no error

Comment: Are they nested? Make sure you have a `<ui-view />` container for the second view

Comment: Please post some code too

Answer (score 0):

Can you add your code to fiddle.
I have created nested states as below and they are working:

```
> .state('home.userAccount', {
>         url: '/userAccount/',
>         templateUrl: 'app/userAccount/userAccount.html',
>         controller: 'userAccount',
>         controllerAs: 'account'
>       })
>       .state('home.userAccount.myProfile', {
>         url: '/userAccount/profile/',
>         templateUrl: 'app/userAccount/userProfile/userProfile.html',
>         controller: 'myProfile',
>         controllerAs: 'profile'
>       }) state('home.userAccount.mySettings', {
>         url: '/userAccount/settings/',
>         templateUrl: 'app/userAccount/settings/settings.html',
>         controller: 'settings',
>         controllerAs: 'settings'
>       });
```